# Performing segue on WKScriptMessage

Tags: xcode, segue, wkwebview

Performing this

```html
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueError2", sender: self)
```

right after receiving a message using:

```html
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
```

drops a *"Attempt to present UIViewController on simpleBrowerVC whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"* error message.

Did the same in other places of the same ViewController (inside a: *didStartProvisionalNavigation*) and worked like a charm.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've discovered that I all the navigation parameters and other configuration stuff for the WKWebView has been set in another viewController, so I assume it's launching from another thread where the current ViewController doesn't even exist...

Will have to figure out how to move data from one thread to the main one :(

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

Gave control to my current viewController, performing

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = self
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKey()